# User provider error symfony

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

I'm developing authentication system with Guard+JWT, and I used [this](http://kolabdigital.com/lab-time/symfony-json-web-tokens-authentication-guard) as a reference. Everything seems to be working. But now I'm facing one problem. When I fist try to access secure resource with generated token, I can able to access it but if I again try to access it gives me an error says

> here is no user provider for user "AppBundle\Document\User

It's like odd even, First request works second not third works and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have something like this in your security.yml file?

```
providers:
    user_db:
        mongodb: {class: AppBundle\Document\User, property: username}
```

Also, you need to put your provider in the firewall section:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        provider: user_db
```

Comment: ohh, I missed to defined provider in firewalls. Thanks a lot.